# How to read [object Object] in RadListView using NativeScript-vue

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I want to show the text from Observable Array but it always shown [object Object].

I tried copy and paste example from `https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/getting-started` but it still shown [object Object]

here is my code like the example from URL above:

```
<template>
  <page>
      <StackLayout>
        <RadListView ref="listView" for="item in itemList" height="50%">
          <v-template>  
           <StackLayout>
              <Label :text="item.name"/>
           <StackLayout>
         </v-template>
        </RadListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </page>
</template>

<script>
 import { ObservableArray } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
         itemList: new ObservableArray([
        {name: 'Item 1', description: 'Item 1 description'},
        {name: 'Item 2', description: 'Item 2 description'},
        {name: 'Item 3', description: 'Item 3 description'},
        ]),
      };
    },


    methods: {


    }
  };

</script>
```

I expect the label show the Observable Array value

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue, can you share a Playground sample?

Comment: here is the URL `https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=beIZRg&v=1` `@Manoj`

Answer (score 0):

RadListView has out of the box support for Vue, you are not suppose the register the element but use the Vue plugin.

```
import RadListView from 'nativescript-ui-listview/vue';
Vue.use(RadListView);
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=beIZRg&v=2)